# Remove empty decimal values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, integer, rounding

I have a dataset with a column this column:

```
    x1
1500.000
1200.000
1300.000
1100.000
```

To properly use functions later on, I need to drop the .000 after each value. This seems to be more so a syntax issue and less about rounding, which is what I see most posts like this recommending. I ultimately want to chop off the tailing zeroes.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you shed some details on the properly use of functions later on? It all sounds a little backwards.

Comment: If you want to treat the values as integers then: `df$x1 <- as.integer(df$x1)`